# how can i get the real size of qlabel in layout?

Tags: python, pyside6

pyside6, my label in horizental layout , I get size() is : (100x30), but the real size more than (400x300) .

```
img1 = QPixmap('src/images/alipay.jpg').scaled(self.ui.img_alipay.size(), aspectMode= Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.ui.img_alipay.setPixmap(img1)
self.ui.img_alipay.repaint()
```

geometry().size() does not work